# Unable to login applications using LDAP alias

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-12.04, openldap, application

We have several applications and we are able to integrate LDAP successfully.

In application we have given base dn as `ou=People,dc=geo,dc=com`  and the user `dn: uid=geo_pc,ou=People,dc=geo,dc=com` can able to login to the application successfully.

Now we created an alias as follows:

```
dn: uid=geo_pc,ou=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=geo,dc=com
aliasedobjectname: uid=geo_pc,ou=People,dc=geo,dc=com 
objectclass: alias
objectclass: extensibleObject
objectclass: top
uid: geo_pc
```

Now in application we have given base dn as `ou=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=geo,dc=com` but with this user `ou=Applications,ou=Groups,dc=geo,dc=com`  we are unable to login to the application.

Please let us know is there any additional configuration we need to done. Can anyone please help us on it.

Thanks

Geo

Answer (score 0):

It does not work. Alias is not for authentication.